# How to pass a variable from one Python script to another?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this question is discussed in forums ad I have read about it a lot but I still dont have solution I need.

Following code is very simplified version of my real code.

My first script is following(kyssa1.py):

```
import os
import sys

def type():
    global dictionary
    dictionary="C:\Python27\Myprojects\physics.txt"
    os.system("C:\Python27\Myprojects\kyssa2.py")


from Tkinter import *
t = Tk()

b = Button(t, text="Start", command = lambda:type())
b.pack(expand=Y)


t.mainloop()
```

And my second script (kyssa2.py) is following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kyssa1 import dictionary   

def open():
    global dictionary
    global lines
    global datafile
    datafile = file(dictionary)
    lines = [line.decode('utf-8').strip() for line in datafile.readlines()]
    for i in lines:
        text.insert(END, i)

open()

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root,font=("Purisa",12))
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I want to do is to open file physics.txt in kyssa2.py and execute command in function open() with this text, but it doesn't wor the way I want to. What happens when I click "Start" button is another window just like defined in "kyssa1.py" appears. How could I just pass variable dictionary from one script to another?

Answer (score 0):

In `kyssa1.py` declare `dictionary` in module scope, i.e.outside of the `type()` function.
You don't need to use `global` in `kyssa2.py`, you can refer directly to `dictionary`.

Also, to open the file, use `open()` rather than `file()`:

```
datafile = open(dictionary)
```